# Get contents of a scala List in a running process?

Tags: scala, heap-dump

I have a running Scala process and want to get the contents of a List in that process. I know the PID of the process and I know the name of the List[String], and I have taken a heap dump with VisualVM. Is there a way for me to find the actual contents of that specific list and save it somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `List[String]` instance is referenced by a class (for example via a `val`) than you can look for the class that holds it.

- You can download [Eclipse Memory Analyzer (MAT)](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) and open your heap dump.
- You can then click the 'Dominator tree' and in the top of the table you can type the name of the class that holds your list.
- If you have found the class right-click it and select 'List objects -> With Incoming References`, that should give you the instances of the class that all could potentially hold the list.
- Right click one of the instances and select 'List objects -> With Outgoing References', that should give you a tree structure where you would find your list
- Note that once you find your list, you can check out the panel on the left (the inspector panel), that contains readable information.

Note: the above steps are from the top of my head, so they might not be completely accurate. This should however give you a good sense of direction.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure in principle it is possible, but surely there's nothing simple or straightforward and off-the-shelf to allow you to do so.

I'd probably go with using the [Java Platform Debugger Architecture (JPDA)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/index.html) and its [Java Debugging Wire Protocol (JDWP)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/jdwp-spec.html) to get at the raw information you'd need. From there you can use Java and / or Scala reflection to discover what to query in the target JVM.

I don't know how much of this is applicable to heap dumps. In the old days, the C / Unix debugging tools could operate on either core dumps or active processes.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the tools references, I'll report back on what worked for me.